# Function equals to location.replace in codeigniter?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, header

I am working on a function that redirect to other page, but I need to block the user from back to the last page

I tried 
`redirect($redirect_url);` but not work

So, I wonder what is the corresponding function eg. `redirect($redirect_url, 'refresh');`?

Also, if I use that function will the set flash data (need to put some result msg in that one-time-only session) not work?

Thanks for helping

Comment: what do you mean "I need to block the user from back to the last page"?

Comment: if the user press back , they can't go to the last page

Comment: There is nothing specific in CI for this, you can try using JS, but most modern browsers will let them go back if they want. Why would you want to prevent them from going back?

Comment: Thanks, paypal seems already handled it